# "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, dictionary

Beginner in Swift here.

I'm trying to create an array out of possible tags from [Cataas API](https://cataas.com/api/tags). Output is a JSON string.

I want to have an array of all possible tags. Here is the relevant code:

```
struct CatArray: Decodable {
    let tag: [String] 
}
```

---

```
func parse(dataJSON: Data) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode([CatArray].self, from: dataJSON)
        print(decodedData.count)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

The error I am getting:

> typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to conform your `CatArray` structure to `Decodable`. Just decode `[String].self` and initialize a new CatArray object with the result.

```
struct CatArray {
    let tag: [String]
}
```

---

```
let jsonData = Data("""
["","#christmascat","2cats","3","4","@Beardlyness","Beer","Belfast","BelfastMet","Black","Buckley","Cat","Cat in a faucet","CryptoWorld Cat","Curious","Cute","FAT","Friends","Fulgencio","Going shopping?","Luz","Maine coon","Maskcat","Mimi","NSFW","Ragdoll","Relaxed","Roar","Shhhsh","Sleepy","Tabby","Tassilo","Teeth","Tired cat","TorWorld Cat","Trippy","Unside down","White","Yeet","advent-calendar-2016","afraid","alcoholic","alien","ange","angel","angry","annilou91","anstrengend","are","artist","attack","attention","attitude","ava","baby","background","banzai","basin","bath","bed","beer","beg","begging","belly","belly rubs","bengal","big","big-eyes","bird","black","black an white","black and white","blue","blur","blurred","boot","box","boxe","british shorthair","british-shorthair","brown","bubble","bucket","bun","burrito","burrito-cat","bw","calico","calvin","cash","cat","cat eyes","cat face","cat kneading","cat_winston","catloaf","cats","catto","chat","check","chonker","christmas","climb","closeup","coat","comfy","computer","confused","cool","costume","couch","cow","cowboy","crazy","crazy russian pussycat","creation","crying","cryptid","cuddle","cuddles","cup","curl","cut","cute","cute baby smol small","cutie","dance","dark","dark vador","darth","darth vader","davie412","dead","derp","detective","dev","devcat","dictator","didizin","dinner!","disappointed","dj","dogstyle","down","dream","drone","drugs","drunk","engineer","evil","exferal","eyes","facecat","fail","fat","fat cat","fedora","felix","file","floor","fluffy","flying","fold","food","freeze","front_view","fun","funny","furious","gg","gif","ginger","glow","goofy","gray","group","grump","grumpy","guilty","gun","halloween","happy","hard","hat","headinacup","hedgehog","hello","hi","hide","ho","ho-wait","howcanihelp","hug","huge","hulu","hunger","icecream","jellybean toes toe beans grey gray mauve","jellybean toes toebeans squished beans","judgemental","jump","jumping","kick","kiss","kitler","kitten","kittenleg","kittens","kitty","knocknoc","kucing","kuro","laying","legs","lights","loaf","logan","lolcat","long","long-cat","lying down","mackerel tabby","mad","mama","marine","mask","meme","metal","misty","mixed","money","moody","morrigan","morrigan witch of the wilds","mousecat","multi","multiple_colors","munchkin","nasty","newyear","nicecat","no","nope","nyancat","nyancat-gif","old","ominous","orange","orange cat","ovni","pain","party","paw","petting","piano","pic","pippin","pirate","playful","please","plot","portrait-worthy","pretty","professional","programmer","puffy","reading","resting","rich","roll","rolling","running","russia","russian blue","sad","sad catto","samurai","sassy","savannah","screm","seeya!","selfie","serious","shark","shit","siamese","sideways","silly","sing","sitting up","sleep","sleeping","sleepy","slick","small","smile","smirk","smol","smug","sofa","soft","some","soon","sound","space","spots","square","stair","staline","star wars","startled","strawberry","stretch","stripes","stupid","stupids","suicide","summon","supermodel","surprised","tabby","tair","tech","thief","tinny","tongue","tortie","tortoiseshell cat","toys","triggered","trump","tryhard","tryhard_cat","tux","tuxedo","tuxedo cat","twitter","twoface","typing","ugg","ugly","unicorn","unit","vader","vador","victorious-cat","victory","waiting","wakup","walking","water","watter cat","weinstein","white","white_fur","window","witch","worker","workspace","wtf","xena","yang","yeay","ying","yoga","young","zombie","なら"]
""".utf8)
```

---

```
do {
    let catArray: CatArray = try .init(tag: JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: jsonData))
    print(catArray.tag)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

Or implement a custom decoder to your `Decodable` structure:

---

```
extension CatArray: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.tag = try decoder.singleValueContainer().decode([String].self)
    }
}
```

---

```
do {
    let catArray = try JSONDecoder().decode(CatArray.self, from: jsonData)
    print(catArray.tag)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

This will print

> ["", "#christmascat", "2cats", "3", "4", "@Beardlyness", "Beer", "Belfast", "BelfastMet", "Black", "Buckley", "Cat", "Cat in a faucet", "CryptoWorld Cat", "Curious", "Cute", "FAT", "Friends", "Fulgencio", "Going shopping?", "Luz", "Maine coon", "Maskcat", "Mimi", "NSFW", "Ragdoll", "Relaxed", "Roar", "Shhhsh", "Sleepy", "Tabby", "Tassilo", "Teeth", "Tired cat", "TorWorld Cat", "Trippy", "Unside down", "White", "Yeet", "advent-calendar-2016", "afraid", "alcoholic", "alien", "ange", "angel", "angry", "annilou91", "anstrengend", "are", "artist", "attack", "attention", "attitude", "ava", "baby", "background", "banzai", "basin", "bath", "bed", "beer", "beg", "begging", "belly", "belly rubs", "bengal", "big", "big-eyes", "bird", "black", "black an white", "black and white", "blue", "blur", "blurred", "boot", "box", "boxe", "british shorthair", "british-shorthair", "brown", "bubble", "bucket", "bun", "burrito", "burrito-cat", "bw", "calico", "calvin", "cash", "cat", "cat eyes", "cat face", "cat kneading", "cat_winston", "catloaf", "cats", "catto", "chat", "check", "chonker", "christmas", "climb", "closeup", "coat", "comfy", "computer", "confused", "cool", "costume", "couch", "cow", "cowboy", "crazy", "crazy russian pussycat", "creation", "crying", "cryptid", "cuddle", "cuddles", "cup", "curl", "cut", "cute", "cute baby smol small", "cutie", "dance", "dark", "dark vador", "darth", "darth vader", "davie412", "dead", "derp", "detective", "dev", "devcat", "dictator", "didizin", "dinner!", "disappointed", "dj", "dogstyle", "down", "dream", "drone", "drugs", "drunk", "engineer", "evil", "exferal", "eyes", "facecat", "fail", "fat", "fat cat", "fedora", "felix", "file", "floor", "fluffy", "flying", "fold", "food", "freeze", "front_view", "fun", "funny", "furious", "gg", "gif", "ginger", "glow", "goofy", "gray", "group", "grump", "grumpy", "guilty", "gun", "halloween", "happy", "hard", "hat", "headinacup", "hedgehog", "hello", "hi", "hide", "ho", "ho-wait", "howcanihelp", "hug", "huge", "hulu", "hunger", "icecream", "jellybean toes toe beans grey gray mauve", "jellybean toes toebeans squished beans", "judgemental", "jump", "jumping", "kick", "kiss", "kitler", "kitten", "kittenleg", "kittens", "kitty", "knocknoc", "kucing", "kuro", "laying", "legs", "lights", "loaf", "logan", "lolcat", "long", "long-cat", "lying down", "mackerel tabby", "mad", "mama", "marine", "mask", "meme", "metal", "misty", "mixed", "money", "moody", "morrigan", "morrigan witch of the wilds", "mousecat", "multi", "multiple_colors", "munchkin", "nasty", "newyear", "nicecat", "no", "nope", "nyancat", "nyancat-gif", "old", "ominous", "orange", "orange cat", "ovni", "pain", "party", "paw", "petting", "piano", "pic", "pippin", "pirate", "playful", "please", "plot", "portrait-worthy", "pretty", "professional", "programmer", "puffy", "reading", "resting", "rich", "roll", "rolling", "running", "russia", "russian blue", "sad", "sad catto", "samurai", "sassy", "savannah", "screm", "seeya!", "selfie", "serious", "shark", "shit", "siamese", "sideways", "silly", "sing", "sitting up", "sleep", "sleeping", "sleepy", "slick", "small", "smile", "smirk", "smol", "smug", "sofa", "soft", "some", "soon", "sound", "space", "spots", "square", "stair", "staline", "star wars", "startled", "strawberry", "stretch", "stripes", "stupid", "stupids", "suicide", "summon", "supermodel", "surprised", "tabby", "tair", "tech", "thief", "tinny", "tongue", "tortie", "tortoiseshell cat", "toys", "triggered", "trump", "tryhard", "tryhard_cat", "tux", "tuxedo", "tuxedo cat", "twitter", "twoface", "typing", "ugg", "ugly", "unicorn", "unit", "vader", "vador", "victorious-cat", "victory", "waiting", "wakup", "walking", "water", "watter cat", "weinstein", "white", "white_fur", "window", "witch", "worker", "workspace", "wtf", "xena", "yang", "yeay", "ying", "yoga", "young", "zombie", "なら"]